# Is there a way to set an Enumerated Property in a class to All available enums?

Tags: c#, enums

First things off, I had no idea what to title this question - I'm even confused how to state it.

Now for the question. Let's take the `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` class where you set it's `NotifyFilter` property:

```
            this.FileSystemWatcher1.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.FileName 
            | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Security 
            | NotifyFilters.Size;
```

That's quite a bit of code to set a single property. Inspecting `NotifyFilter`, it is an enumeration. Is there a '*lazy*' or '*shortcut*' way to set all these properties at once? I know it's not necessarily needed, but my curiosity is piqued.

`this.FileSystemWatcher1.NotifyFilter = <NotifyFilters.All>` ?

Comment: I prefer to define this sort of thing explicitly, e.g. in a field called All. You could then exclude specific enum values by using `~`.

Comment: @GregRos Can you somehow demonstrate what you mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could always do something like this,

```
NotifyFilter ret = 0;
foreach(NotifyFilter v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(NotifyFilter)))
{
    ret |= v;   
}
```

I don't know of a better way, unfortunately. But you could always throw that in a generic utility method.

```
private static T GetAll<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
       throw new NotSupportedException(); // You'd want something better here, of course.
    }

    long ret = 0; // you could determine the type with reflection, but it might be easier just to use multiple methods, depending on how often you tend to use it.
    foreach(long v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
    {
        ret |= v;
    }

    return (T)ret;
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you could say `foreach(NotifyFilter in Enum.GetValues(typeof(NotifyFilter)))` saves the cast inside the foreach body.

Comment: Good one. I am working on some major personal projects, and would like to keep my application fast. Didn't occur to me to use generic methods to nail this problem.

Comment: Constraint your `T` to `where T: struct, IConvertible` and check `if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) { throw ... }`

Comment: `(T)ret` doesn't compile for me -- but I'm stuck on c# 3.0.  Does it work in 4.0/4.5?

Comment: @dbc That is disallowed in any version of C#. There is no conversion from `int` to a type argument `T` (no matter what constraints `T` carries).

Comment: If you assume that the underlying type of the enum `T` is `int`, maybe you should check that where you check `typeof(T).IsEnum`. Otherwise you will get unexpected behavior if some enum uses `long` as its underlying type.

Comment: @Noobgrammer Maybe it is OK to set all flags, even those not used or named. In that case you can just do `this.FileSystemWatcher1.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters)(~0);` or (equivalently) `this.FileSystemWatcher1.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters)(-1);`. But be sure to check if the underlying type of `NotifyFilters` is `int` ([it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx)).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thanks, good point. I realized that as I had to leave. I was going to add in the support for `long`, but I figured this gives the gist to people so I left it up.

Comment: I assume `ret |= (v;` is a typo?

Comment: @Blorgbeard that's what I get for answering in a hurry. Thanks for pointing that out! Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a way without writing your own method - as correctly answered elsewhere.

If the enum was yours to change you could add a new value

```
All = ~0
```

Answer (score 3):

If the enumeration has the `Flags` attribute applied on it you can add the numbers equivalent to the desired enum members and then assign it.

In the example in your question sum up 4+64+32+16+8 = 124 then you can write

```
this.FileSystemWatcher1.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters) 124;
```

Of course this takes away the readability of an enum and dramatically causes maintenance issues, but as you said it's for our lazies:

```
public class Program
{
    [Flags]
    enum Enum:int
    {
        a = 1,
        b = 2
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Enum x = (Enum) 3;
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());

    }
}
```

Output:

```
a,b
```

UPDATE:

I almost forgot. You can of course pass this string to `Enum.Parse` and get the desired value:

```
this.FileSystemWatcher1.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilter) Enum.Parse(typeof(NotifyFilter), 
"Attributes,CreationTime,FileName,LastAccess,LastWrite,Security,Size");
```

Comment: That's pretty freaky. Didn't know you could do this

Comment: It still freaks myself out, but as you said: curiosity and of course laziness.

Comment: I can imagine this landing in spaghetti code , and the next developer working on this jumping from a 27 floor building

Comment: Exactly. I myself hate this, but comes handy in some tight spots.

Answer (score 3):

Writing a generic utility to mask together all the values in a c# enum turns out to be much more difficult than one would imagine, because

1. The underlying type of an enum can be byte, short, int or long; signed or unsigned.
2. There is no way to cast an object directly to a generic enum, perhaps because there's no enum constraint built into c#.  One must box instead, then unbox.
3. All the enum utilities date from c# 1.0 and so are rather crufty.

This is the best I could do.  I made use of the following:

1. [Cast Int to Generic Enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387095/cast-int-to-generic-enum-in-c-sharp/10387134#10387134)
2. [Enum type constraints in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331739/enum-type-constraints-in-c-sharp/1416660#1416660)

Would this be easier in c++/CLI?

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains generic utilities for enums, constrained for enums only.
/// </summary>
public sealed class EnumHelper : Enums<Enum>
{
    private EnumHelper()
    {
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// For use by EnumHelper, not for direct use.
/// </summary>
public abstract class Enums<TEnumBase> where TEnumBase : class, IConvertible
{
    private static void ThrowOnEnumWithoutFlags<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct, TEnumBase
    {
        var attributes = typeof(TEnum).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FlagsAttribute), false);
        if (attributes.Length == 0)
        {
            throw (new ArgumentException("The generic argument [<T>] must be an enumeration with the [FlagsAttribute] applied.", "T: " + typeof(TEnum).FullName));
        }
    }

    public static TEnum GetAll<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct, TEnumBase
    {
        ThrowOnEnumWithoutFlags<TEnum>();
        var underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TEnum));
        if (underlyingType == typeof(ulong))
        {
            ulong value = 0;
            foreach (var v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
                // Not sure I need the culture but Microsoft passes it in Enum.ToUInt64(Object value) - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs
                value |= Convert.ToUInt64(v, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
            return (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), value);
        }
        else
        {
            long value = 0;
            foreach (var v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
                // Not sure I need the culture but Microsoft passes it in Enum.ToUInt64(Object value) - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs
                value |= Convert.ToInt64(v, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), value);
        }
    }
```

I have tested on byte, sbyte, short, int, long, ushort, uint and ulong types.

**Update** simplified as per hvd's suggestion.

Comment: +1 You do need separate handlers for `long` and `ulong` to handle values that are out of `long`'s range, but for all other types, you can use the `long` version: simply use `Convert.ToInt64` and `Enum.ToObject` to perform the conversions. (And for consistency, you can use `Convert.ToUInt64` and `Enum.ToObject` for the `ulong` version.)