# How to return back to an enum menu in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have written a small console application that is like a small shop where you can select items that you would like to buy from enum menu's. One of the options that a person can pick is that once they've gone into a "sub enum" they can then return back to the "main enum menu".

Once the user has gone into the "sweets" option, I want then to be able select option 4 which will take them back to the menu options where they can choose to either get more sweets, get meat, get produce or exit the menu and go to where they can see their total.

I am making use of switch statements of the options.

```
            Console.WriteLine("Please select an option between 1 and 4: ");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Sweets");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Meats");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Produce");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Exit");
            Option = Console.ReadLine();

        if (Option == "1")
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Please select an option between 1 and 4: ");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Chocolate R10");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Winegums R12");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Astros R15");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Back");
            int sweets = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Please, share the complete sample

Comment: I have tried, unfortunately it is too long so would have to send it in multiple replies

Comment: There are no "replies" here as this is a wiki and not your usual forum format. A question should focus on the crux of the problem. If it's as long as you say, you need to break the problem down to something smaller and present a [mre]. What you've shown is incomplete.

Comment: So, what's the problem? Put all this code into `while(true){...}`. 

Comment: Check this similiar question (and answer): https://stackoverflow.com/a/59595555/583037

Answer (score 0):

I have actually made something similar in Turbo Pascal back in 1994 :-) Fun times...
This is a recursive thing. Split all sub options out in separate classes in memory, holding the id and text. Then make a general function that turns a set of menues into text in the console and display the correct menu inside a function that calls itself (with parameters to the correct set of menu) unless "exit" is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I had nothing to do at home, so I made this program for you. It utilizes a [TreeNode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) data structure. The `TreeNode` data structure makes it possible to have an "unlimited" amount of sub categories/products. It is also easy to traverse it by setting the node `menu` to its parent or selected child. You need to add/change products to the `Populate()` method and maybe change the `MenuItem` properties to your choice (i.e. `Price` of `Product` is of type `int`).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class Program
{
    private static List<Product> _cart = new List<Product>();
    static void Main()
    {
        var menu = Populate();
        Run(menu);
    }

    private static void ClickToContinue(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{message}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ShowCart()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Your cart:");
        for (int i = 0; i < _cart.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-4} | {1,-15} | {2,5}", (i + 1).ToString(), _cart[i].Name, _cart[i].Price));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-4} | {1,-15} | {2,5}", "Tot:", $"{_cart.Count()} items", _cart.Sum(item => item.Price).ToString()));
    }

    private static void PrintMenu(TreeNode<MenuItem> menu, string title)
    {
        title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) ? string.Empty : $"> {title.Trim()}";
        var menuTitle = $"{menu.Value.Id}. {menu.Value.Name}".Trim();
        if (menu.Parent == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{menuTitle} {title}\n");
            return;
        }
        PrintMenu(menu.Parent, $"{menuTitle} {title}");
    }

    private static void Run(TreeNode<MenuItem> menu)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            PrintMenu(menu, string.Empty);
            var selectedItem = SelectMenuItem(menu);
            switch (selectedItem.Value)
            {
                case Category _:
                    menu = selectedItem;
                    break;
                case Product p:
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nYou added {p.Name} to the cart.\n");
                    _cart.Add(p);
                    if (selectedItem.Parent != null)
                        menu = selectedItem.Parent;
                    ClickToContinue("\n\nPress any key to continue");
                    break;
                case Cart _:
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    ShowCart();
                    if (selectedItem.Parent != null)
                        menu = selectedItem.Parent;
                    ClickToContinue("\n\nPress any key to continue");
                    break;
                case GoBack b:
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    if (b.IsExit)
                    {
                        ShowCart();
                        ClickToContinue("\n\nGoodbye!\n\nPress any key to continue");
                        return;
                    }
                    menu = (selectedItem.Parent?.Parent != null) ? selectedItem.Parent.Parent : selectedItem.Parent;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception($"{selectedItem.Value} not implemented");
                case null:
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selectedItem.Value));
            }
        }
    }

    private static TreeNode<MenuItem> SelectMenuItem(TreeNode<MenuItem> menuItem)
    {
        var minValue = menuItem.Children.OrderBy(i => i.Value.Id).FirstOrDefault().Value.Id;
        var maxValue = menuItem.Children.OrderBy(i => i.Value.Id).LastOrDefault().Value.Id;
        Console.WriteLine($"Please select an option between {minValue} and {maxValue}: ");
        foreach (var child in menuItem.Children)
        {
            var price = child.Value is Product ? $"{(child.Value as Product).Price}" : string.Empty;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-4} | {1,-15} | {2,5}", child.Value.Id.ToString(), child.Value.Name, price));
        }

        var selectedId = TryParseInput();

        while (true)
        {
            var selectedItem = menuItem.Children.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Value.Id == selectedId);
            if (selectedItem != null)
            {
                return selectedItem;
            }

            //Selected id does not exist in the menu
            Console.WriteLine($"Please choose from one of the options.");
            selectedId = TryParseInput();
        }
    }

    private static TreeNode<MenuItem> Populate()
    {
        var menu = new TreeNode<MenuItem>(new Category(1, "Menu"));
        var sweets = new TreeNode<MenuItem>(new Category(1, "Sweets"));
        sweets.AddChildren(new List<MenuItem> {
                new Product(1, "Chocolate R10", 15),
                new Product(2, "Winegums R12", 20),
                new Product(3, "Astros R15", 11),
                new GoBack(9, "Back"),
            });
        var meats = new TreeNode<MenuItem>(new Category(2, "Meats"));
        meats.AddChildren(new List<MenuItem> {
                new Product(1, "Chicken", 13),
                new Product(2, "Beef", 14),
                new Product(3, "Seafood", 17),
                new GoBack(9, "Back"),
            });
        var produce = new TreeNode<MenuItem>(new Category(3, "Produce"));
        produce.AddChildren(new List<MenuItem> {
                new Product(1, "Apple", 17),
                new Product(2, "Tomato", 25),
                new Product(3, "Orange", 24),
                new GoBack(9, "Back"),
            });
        var cart = new TreeNode<MenuItem>(new Cart(4, "Cart"));
        var exit = new TreeNode<MenuItem>(new GoBack(5, "Exit", true));
        menu.AddChildren(new List<TreeNode<MenuItem>> {
                sweets,
                meats,
                produce,
                cart,
                exit,
            });

        return menu;
    }

    private static int TryParseInput()
    {
        int returnInt;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out returnInt))
        {
            //Cannot parse input as an integer
            Console.WriteLine($"Selection is not a number. Please try again.");
        }

        return returnInt;
    }
}

public abstract class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

public class GoBack : MenuItem
{
    public GoBack(int id, string name, bool isExit = false) : base(id, name)
    {
        IsExit = isExit;
    }

    public bool IsExit { get; set; }
}

public class Cart : MenuItem
{
    public Cart(int id, string name) : base(id, name) { }
}

public class Category : MenuItem
{
    public Category(int id, string name) : base(id, name) { }
}

public class Product : MenuItem
{
    public Product(int id, string name, int price) : base(id, name)
    {
        Price = price;
    }
    public int Price { get; private set; }
}

public class TreeNode<T>
{
    private readonly T _value;
    private readonly List<TreeNode<T>> _children = new List<TreeNode<T>>();

    public TreeNode(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public TreeNode<T> this[int i] => _children[i];

    public TreeNode<T> Parent { get; private set; }

    public T Value { get { return _value; } }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<TreeNode<T>> Children
    {
        get { return _children.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    public TreeNode<T> AddChild(T value)
    {
        var node = new TreeNode<T>(value) { Parent = this };
        _children.Add(node);
        return node;
    }

    public TreeNode<T> AddChild(TreeNode<T> node)
    {
        node.Parent = this;
        _children.Add(node);
        return node;
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<TreeNode<T>> AddChildren(List<T> nodes)
    {
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            AddChild(node);
        }
        return Children;
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<TreeNode<T>> AddChildren(List<TreeNode<T>> nodes)
    {
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            AddChild(node);
        }
        return Children;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1. Menu

Please select an option between 1 and 5:
1    | Sweets          |
2    | Meats           |
3    | Produce         |
4    | Cart            |
5    | Exit            |
4

Your cart:
1    | Apple           |    17
2    | Orange          |    24
3    | Apple           |    17
4    | Astros R15      |    11
Tot: | 4 items         |    69


Press any key to continue
```