# How to cast a variable of an enum generic type to int and back

Tags: c#, enums, casting

I am using C# to write a class that takes an enum type parameter, like this:

```
class EnumWrapper<T>
    where T: Enum
{
}
```

Inside the class, I have a method that takes an argument of type T, and I need to cast it to an int, like this:

```
void DoSomething(T arg)
{
    int a = (int)arg;
}
```

But the compiler issues a CS0030 error "Cannot convert type 'T' to 'int'. Something similar happens when I try to cast an int back into a T. However, this works with a fixed enum type that is not provided via a type parameter. For example, this works fine:

```
void DoSomething(DayOfWeek arg)
{
    int a = (int)arg;
}
```

Why is this happening, and how can I cast between a generic enum type and int?

Comment: Remember that enums can have any integer base type -- you can have `enum Foo : ulong` if you so wish. What do you want your code to do in that case?

Comment: @canton7: Yes, I am aware of this. :-)

Comment: That's the "why is this happening" part. For the "How can I cast..." part, answer my question: What do you want your code to do in that case?

Comment: I'm wondering why you need such a wrapper class.   It sounds like you are possibly doing something 'unusual', hence your problem, when there may be a better way to solve your actual problem without a wrapper

Comment: @Neil, I am developing a wrapper because I need two features: a string description of each enum value, and hierarchically organised values.

Comment: @CesarGon Please check out the end of my answer :) I also had a very similar problem a couple of years ago

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü: Yes, thank you!

Comment: String descriptions should probably use the `[Description]` attribute (which already supports resx/translations etc).   Hierarchy, could also come from a custom attribute, I guess  `[Hierarchy("parent")]` ?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, @Neil. We are currently exploring alternative approaches, and attributes are one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add [`IConvertible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=net-5.0) to generic constraint and use `ToInt32` method, something like

```cs
class EnumWrapper<T>
    where T : Enum, IConvertible
{
    void DoSomething(T arg)
    {
        int a = arg.ToInt32(null);
    }
}
```

Have a look at [the `Enum` constraint](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-new-generics-constraints-in-c-7-3/#the-enum-constraint) for details. Also, as mentioned in comments, it isn't necessary that your `enum` is based on `int` type

Comment: Alternatively, skip the constraint and call `Convert.ToInt32(arg)` (which internally tests for `IConvertible`).

Comment: Lacks the "back" part of the title. But that is already explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10387134/284240